# Azure Storage Account - Geo-Replication : what is the frequency of the Geo-Replication and what would be the data loss in case of failure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account, geo-replication

I have an Azure Storage Account in **WEST US** and configured Geo-Replication to sync with **EAST US**.

I want to know

1. How often Geo-Replication sync gets executed?
2. In case of WEST US regional failure and happen to failover to EAST US, what would be the data loss?
3. Is there way to control the frequency of the Geo-Replication sync

Comment: Answer to #1 and #2 can be found in the docs @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy

Comment: as per the document, there would be a data loss up to15 minutes

Comment: Correct: *Because data is replicated to the secondary region asynchronously, a failure that affects the primary region may result in data loss if the primary region cannot be recovered. The interval between the most recent writes to the primary region and the last write to the secondary region is known as the recovery point objective (RPO). The RPO indicates the point in time to which data can be recovered. Azure Storage typically has an RPO of less than 15 minutes, although there's currently no SLA on how long it takes to replicate data to the secondary region.*

Comment: The replication is an ongoing process, hence there is no frequency. It can be delayed to typically 15 minutes. No SLA is given.